# pyqt disconnect slots. New style

Tags: python, pyqt, signals, disconnect, slot

I assign a slot with this.

```
...
self.query = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)            
self.query.textChanged.connect(lambda: self.makeThread(self.googleSearch()))
self.query.returnPressed.connect(lambda: self.launchNavigator(1))
...
```

but how can I disconnect? I tried with this but it does not work...

```
self.query.textChanged.disconnect(lambda: self.makeThread(self.googleSearch()))
self.query.returnPressed.disconnect(lambda: self.launchNavigator(1))
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The lambda expressions return *different* functions that (more or less by chance ;) ) will do the same thing. Therefore, what you connected your signal to is not the same thing as the second lambda you're using when trying to disconnect it; see this example:

```
>>> f = lambda x: x
>>> g = lambda x: x
>>> f is g
False
```

You can either use `self.query.textChanged.disconnect()` without any parameters, which will disconnect the signal from *all* slots (which might be ok if you only have that one connection) or you will have to store a reference to the lambda somewhere:

```
self.func1 = lambda: self.makeThread(self.googleSearch())
self.query.textChanged.connect(self.func1)
...
self.query.textChanged.disconnect(self.func1)
```

Comment: What you said about lambas, is that true for `functools.partial` as well?

Answer (score 5):

There is an elegant way of disconnecting a signal using the QConnection object returned by the original connection. So:

```
self.conn1 = self.query.textChanged.connect(lambda: self.makeThread(self.googleSearch()))
self.conn2 = self.query.returnPressed.connect(lambda: self.launchNavigator(1))
```

And then subsequently:

```
self.disconnect(self.conn1)
self.disconnect(self.conn2)
```

This feature was not implemented prior to PyQt 5.13.1, although it has existed in Qt for a long time.

Comment: This should definetely be the accepted answer, it's the cleanest way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add a caveat/extension to @rainer's answer pertaining to bound methods. Keep in mind that binding a method to an instance (e.g., by writing `self.slotname`) actually creates a new closure every time (as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41900639/2988730) question).

You would therefore have the same problem doing

```
def test_slot(self):
    self.makeThread(self.googleSearch())

...

    self.query.textChanged.connect(self.test_slot)

...

    self.query.textChanged.disconnect(self.test_slot)
```

as you did with the original `lambda` in your question. The solution is to store the *closure* `self.test_slot` in an attribute, as @rainer suggests. This is necessary because a new object that is roughly equivalent to `lambda: type(self).test_slot(self)` is generated every time you write `self.test_slot` in your code. The following will work fine as long as you do the book-keeping accurately:

```
    self.func = self.test_slot
    self.query.textChanged.connect(self.func)

...

    self.query.textChanged.disconnect(self.func)
```