# Pass object method as lambda or partial function, replacing self parameter with target object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, partials

**Use case:** Lets say that I have a very large set of Pandas Series objects and I wish to apply the `.drop_na()` method to all of them. However because they are so large I must use a function that will perform this with `multiprocessing`, by accepting a list of objects and using each object in the list as the argument to a method (which is also passed as an object).

Given that the first, and implicit, argument to an object method is self.

Can I use a lambda, partial or other trickery to pass the `.drop_na()` method and replace the self argument in `.drop_na()` with a specific instance of a series? Is this possible in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The first argument is only "implicit" when the method is bound to an object that is an instance of the class using `.` notation, e.g.

```
sr = Series(...)
sr.drop_na()
```

In this case, `sr.drop_na` is actually a closure that replaces the `self` parameter of `Series.drop_na` with a reference to `sr`, sort of like

```
lambda: Series.drop_na(sr)
```

You can always call the method from the class directly and pass the `self` parameter explicitly. The example above can be rewritten as:

```
sr = Series(...)
Series.drop_na(sr)
```

You can pass the function `Series.drop_na` around as necessary and call it on whatever objects you need. Notice that `Series.drop_na` takes a single parameter, while `sr.drop_na` does not.

This is not trickery and is in fact a deliberate design choice in the language that is intended to be used for cases just like yours (and many others as well).

Comment: Thank you. I feel like closures in python are not discussed enough.

Comment: Yes, the rules can be a bit obscure at times. This particular one is pretty simple, but it took me a long time to realize that a *different* closure is created every time you access a method via `.` on the object: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41900639/2988730

Comment: Nitpick: `sr.drop_na` is the closure; `sr.drop_na()` is the application of the closure to its remaining required arguments (of which there are none).

Comment: @chepner. Good catch, fixed.